# How I can update data index from ajax jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have and array of data by ajax get method. I output this data by its index number as data[0]. for next data I click on a button and need to update the index "here 0" in data to get data[1] and so on. Here is my code, I have tested with defining id after .done but doesn't work.

```
     $.ajax({
        url: `/ajaxweblog`,
        id: 0,
      }).done(function (data) {

        $("#rast").on('click', function () {
          this.id += 1;
        });
        $(".title-of").html(data[this.id]['title']);
        $(".subtitle-of").html(data[this.id]['subtitle']);
        $(".thearticel").html(data[this.id]['body']);
        $(".article-img").attr('src', '/images/articles/' + data[this.id]['image']);
      })
```

Comment: Don't create event handlers inside event handlers.

Comment: That being said, "it doesn't work" is not an error description. It lacks both what you expect and what happens instead.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let index = 0;
let data;

function updateDOM() {
  $('.title-of').html(data[index]['title']);
  $('.subtitle-of').html(data[index]['subtitle']);
  $('.thearticel').html(data[index]['body']);
  $('.article-img').attr('src', '/images/articles/' + data[index]['image']);
}

$("#rast").on('click', function() {
  index += 1;
  // check if the data variable has been assigned a value and if the next index exists
  if (data && data[index]) {
    updateDOM();
  }
});

// 'id' is not a valid key for the $.ajax settings object
$.ajax({
  url: '/ajaxweblog'
}).done(function(res) {
  data = res;
  updateDOM();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove click handle code that you inserted inside '.done'

`$("#rast").on('click', function () {
          this.id += 1;
        });` 
then you have to keep a copy of response object and on click of a button (or change in the id), you have to pass updated JSON data for table to render